# Why Assign Class Fields Outside Constructor

Tags: python, oop

I recently saw code that assigns a list to an object's field after the constructor is invoked.

```
# Inside the "Block" class definition
def __init__(self, name, access, address=None):
    ModuleBS.__init__(self, name, address)
    self.access = access
    self.mem_list = [] 



# Calling the constructor
tmp_blk = Block(block_name, name, access, sys_addr)
tmp_blk.mem_list = memory_list          ## assignment occurs after constructor invoked
```

Is there a reason for this? Why would this be preferred over initializing mem_list inside the constructor instead, passing memory_list as a constructor argument?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, `mem_list` IS being initialised in class' `__init__`:

```py
# Inside the "Block" class definition
def __init__(self, name, access, address=None):
    ...
    self.mem_list = []
```

Later call was just an value change - some would just use `append()` or `insert()`, some would just pass existing list.

As for your second question, it's perfectly okay to do it both way - I'm mostly writing my classes that way I can initialise some variable with class call, with a simple check to see if data passed is valid, and later change that variable on demand - as long as I my init method's doesn't have a bunch of parameters.

In that case it may be just simpler to initialise a class with only necessary fields (with some 'default' values for other) and later just change those values directly.